# Vue property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

When trying this code in an online compiler it works fine
but on localhost I see this problem:

> Property or method "searchfunc" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components)

**main.js**

```js
var Hotels = [
  { name: "Sham", city: "Damascus", bed: 1, price: 100, id: "h1" },
  { name: "Shahbaa", city: "Aleppo", bed: 3, price: 200, id: "h2" },
  { name: "abcd", city: "Homs", bed: 5, price: 350, id: "h3" },
];

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
  searchs:'',
  Hotels,
  computed: {
    searchfunc() {
      return this.Hotels.filter((srh) => {
        return srh.price >= parseInt(this.searchs);
      });
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

**Home.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">

<form>
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="searchs"
      placeholder="Search.."
      
    />
</form>
<p v-for="ps in searchfunc" :key="ps">{{ps.name}}</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Home",
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when trying to use a property or method in the template (or render function) that doesn't exist on the component instance.

In this case it's because `searchs` and `searchFunc` variables used in the template of *Home.vue* are not found below on the instance.  They are in the wrong file and need to be moved into *Home.vue*.  Data needs to also go inside the `data` option:

**main.js**

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

**Home.vue**

```js
<script>
const Hotels = [
  { name: "Sham", city: "Damascus", bed: 1, price: 100, id: "h1" },
  { name: "Shahbaa", city: "Aleppo", bed: 3, price: 200, id: "h2" },
  { name: "abcd", city: "Homs", bed: 5, price: 350, id: "h3" },
];
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      searchs: '',
      Hotels,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    searchfunc() {
      return this.Hotels.filter((srh) => {
        return srh.price >= parseInt(this.searchs);
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```